# Filter in binding to CollectionViewSource in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm doing some fixes in a project where I need to edit an entity named Tariff, which have as a property a collection of TariffSteps. The model was made with Entity Framework Code First:

```
namespace pbxControl.model.Classes
{
    public class Tariff : PropertyChangedNotifier
    {
        public int TariffId { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        // ...

        public ObservableCollection<TariffStep> TariffSteps { get; set; }

        // ...
    }

    public class TariffStep : PropertyChangedNotifier
    {
        public int TariffStepId { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public int Duration { get; set; }

        // ...

        #region references

        public virtual ObservableCollection<Tariff> Tariffs { get; set; }

        // ...
```

Which created a many to many relationship in the DB through an intermediate table "TariffStepTariffs".

In the UI the interface is based in a master - detail scenario where an outer grid is binded to a CollectionViewSource (on tariff collection), inside that grid there is a Datagrid where the tariffs are shown (master), and another grid where the selected tariff is detailed.

Originally, before the new fixes were implemented, the way of dealing with the tariffSteps was as follow: an area for add / remove/ modify TariffSteps in the Model (TariffStepsGrid), and another area where the client could add tariffSteps from the first area to a Tariff (TariffTariffStepsGrid). The idea was that several tariff could share the same step if they have the same properties:

[previous way of assign tariffSteps to tariff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZraR.png)

```
<TabItem Name="Tariff_Tab" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TabIndex="5" Header="Tarifas" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalTab}">

    <Grid x:Name="TariffsGrid" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource tariffViewSource}}">

        <Grid x:Name="TariffDetailGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding}">

            <Grid  x:Name="TariffDetailPropertiesGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding}">

                <!-- Some controls for properties of the Tariff -->

            </Grid>

            <Grid x:Name="CurrencyGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{StaticResource currencyViewSource}">

                <!-- This grid is for management of another entity (Currency) -->

            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="TariffTariffStepsGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="360"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid x:Name="TariffTariffStep" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding Path=TariffSteps}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">

                    <ListBox x:Name="TariffStepList1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="130" Width="200" Margin="0 15 0 5" 
                                 TabIndex="22">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="2 2">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DurationV, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="0" Width="60" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PeriodV, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Width="60" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CostV, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="2" Width="60" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

                </Grid>

                <Grid x:Name="TariffTariffStepsButtons" Grid.Column="1">

                    <Grid Height="50">
                        <Button x:Name="TariffTariffStepAdd" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                            Click="TariffTariffStepAdd_Click" Background="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource LessThanButton}">
                        </Button>
                        <Button x:Name="TariffTariffStepRemove" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                            Click="TariffTariffStepRemove_Click" Background="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource GreaterThanButton}">
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>

            </Grid>

            <Grid x:Name="TariffStepsGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{StaticResource tariffStepViewSource}">

                <!-- Some controls for properties of the TariffStep and buttons for add / remove a TariffStep -->

                <ListBox x:Name="TariffStepList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                         VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="130" Width="200" Margin="0 15 20 5" 
                         SelectionChanged="TariffStep_SelectionChanged" GotFocus="TariffStepList_GotFocus" TabIndex="22">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="2 2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DurationV, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="0" Width="60" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PeriodV, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Width="60" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CostV, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="2" Width="60" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid  x:Name="TariffActionGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"><!-- Buttons for save, etc. --> </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="AllTariffsGrid" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

        <DataGrid x:Name="ListTarif1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="255" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="760" Margin="20,25,20,0" SelectionChanged="ListTarif1_SelectionChanged"
                   CanUserAddRows="False">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Descripción" Binding="{Binding DescriptionV, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="152"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fecha de Inicio" Binding="{Binding StartDateV}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="152"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fecha Final" Binding="{Binding EndDateV}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="152"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CurrencyV.Code}" Header="Moneda" IsReadOnly="True" Width="152"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding InitialCostV}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="152">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <AccessText TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center">Costo Inicial</AccessText>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>

</TabItem>
```

For populating the TariffStepList listbox (the one for the collection of all tariffs) in code behind was implemented a filter that allowed in the view of the tariffStepViewSource only the tariffsteps that were not already assigned to the tariff:

```
public void TariffStepsNonInTariffFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    TariffStep tariffStep = e.Item as TariffStep;
    var Tariff = ListTarif1.SelectedItem as Tariff;
    if (Tariff != null)
    {
        if (tariffStep.Tariffs.Contains(Tariff))
        {
            e.Accepted = false;
            return;
        }
    }
    e.Accepted = true;
}
```

That filter was assigned to the tariffStepViewSource only when the app has the Tariff tab on focus, when the focus were to another tab, it was unasigned.

Well, all that worked like a charm, but in the new design there was no need for the tariffStepViewSource because the tariffSteps were assigned directly to the tariff (it didn't matter that they were repeated in the database). As can be seen in the following xaml, the binding is to the collection of tariffSteps of the tariff ( DataContext="{Binding Path=TariffSteps} ).

```
<TabItem Name="Tariff_Tab" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TabIndex="5" Header="Tarifas" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalTab}">

    <Grid x:Name="TariffsGrid" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource tariffViewSource}}">

        <Grid x:Name="TariffDetailGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding}">

            <!-- grids & controls for properties of the Tariff & the Currency entity -->
                            
            <Grid x:Name="TariffTariffStepsGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                DataContext="{Binding Path=TariffSteps}">

                <TextBox x:Name="TariffStepCost" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="0,115,225,0" Height="25" Width="100" 
                         Text="{Binding Path=CostV, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=N2}"
                         LostFocus="TariffStepCost_LostFocus" TabIndex="21"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.Source.Count, Converter={StaticResource IsEnabledBySourceCountConverter}, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>

                <Label x:Name="TariffStepCostlabel" Height="25" Content="Costo:"  Margin="0,115,325,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                   VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Width="55" Padding="0"/>

                <!-- Some more controls for other properties of the TariffStep and buttons for add / remove a TariffStep -->

                <ListBox x:Name="TariffStepList1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TariffSteps}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="130" Width="200" Margin="0 15 20 5" 
                                 TabIndex="22">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="2 2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DurationV, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="0" Width="60" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PeriodV, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Width="60" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CostV, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="2" Width="60" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <!-- TariffActionGrid && AllTariffsGrid -->

    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

The fact is that, no matter what I do, if I remove the filter from code behind, in the listbox "TariffStepList1" nothing get shown. I can add new tariffSteps and save the context, but when I close the app and open it again, nothing is shown. I've tested all option, even creating new ListBox, button, etc. in a different tab. I have checked that there is no remaining references to tariffStepViewSource in the whole project, still there is no way the tariffSteps get shown.

In another tab I have the same xaml controls structure in which a navigation property is modified with exactly the same master - detail scenario (an entity named Extension which have a collection of associated email addresses), and there is no problem there. As soon as I re-incorporate the tariffStepViewSource, with it corresponding filter, the tariffSteps get shown, even when there binding in the Grid is not to the viewsource.

Comment: Debugging the binding to an ObservableCollection is pretty straight forward. At a time where no data is shown in your controls (while the collection should contain said data), inspect the collection and look if the data is inside. If not, there is your issue. If the data is there but the controls are empty, chances are something is wrong with your binding, and you might get a binding error.

Comment: I suspect there is an issue with your DataContext, so you might just get a binding error. TariffTariffStepsGrid has its DataContext set to TariffSteps, TariffStepList1 tries to bind to TariffSteps. I suspect the ListBox TariffStepList1 inherits the DataContext from its parent and thus the binding to TariffSteps fails. I think setting the DataContext of the grid controls is pretty confusing anyways, so you might want to check that out.

Comment: Hi @Shrimperator, inside the collection there was data, I checked that. Regarding setting the DataContext to the Grid I've done that all over the rest of the application, which have way more tabs and entities, and it worked fine in everyother place. Maybe it's not exactly the correct way of doing it, and the problem was hidden down until now. That's exactly why I'm asking about it, because maybe someone can tell me what is wrong because has seen it before. When I have a time I'll check the documentation and refresh my knowledge about WPF, unfortunatelly it couldn't be right now.

Comment: Do you get any binding errors? Otherwise, you might want to try and refresh the ListBox in question manually and see if that loads the data correctly: I think `TariffStepList1.Items.Refresh();` should do a full refresh. Also, try if changing the binding from `{Binding Path=TariffSteps}` to `{Binding TariffSteps}` changes anything. I think both methods use the same DataContext, but use a different way of linking the data - I'm unsure if the `Path` approach is suited for an ObservableCollection.